# How to use groupby and sum

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I am working on a dataframe where i have to groupby and sum. The way i read is i have to groupby first and select the columns i want to sum. Is there any difference between using groupby first and then selecting the column i want to sum or selecting the column i want to sum first and using the groupby afterwards.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby('Manager')[['Transaction', 'Defects']].sum()

grouped_df = df[['Transaction','Defects']].groupby('Manager').sum()
```

Is the above code same or can produce different results at times.

Comment: second line usually yield an error since `'Manager'` is not a column of `df[['Transaction', 'Defects']]`.

Comment: have you create a test dataframe? would be really useful in this case to create example rows and run.

Answer (score 2):

```
grouped_df = df[['Transaction','Defects']].groupby('Manager').sum()
```

will yield an error since 'Manager' is not contained in the data frame df[['Transaction','Defects']].

The first line is correct.

Personally, I prefer grouping using the agg method, you should give it a look. You can use different aggregation functions. Ex:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby('Manager').agg({'Transaction': 'sum','Defects': 'mean'})
```

Comment: Ok thanks. In my case it didn't yield any errors from both methods so, i thought i would ask here.I also believed that first was was the correct way of doing it.

Comment: If i do it like this then it would also work i guess.

grouped_df = df[['Transaction','Defects']].groupby(df['Manager']).sum()